# Rails-4.2 mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am reusing a mailer in a related Rails-4.2 based application that was originally written for a non-RoR, stand-alone, script.  The script will continue to run as a separate application.  However, as originally designed the script only used active-record and action mailler.  Thus the full RoR directory structure was truncated.  The app directory did not exist and the mailers were placed in a subdirectory of lib: `~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer` and the templates were placed in the views subdirectory to this: `~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views`

The mailer class contains this:

```
class HllThForexMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  . . .
  def forex_hll_commercial_rates(
    . . .
puts( File.expand_path( 'views', File.dirname( __FILE__ ) ).inspect )
mail( :to => recipients,
      :from => fm_address,
      :subject => subject,
      :template_path => File.expand_path( 'views',
        File.dirname( __FILE__ ) )
    ) do | format |
  format.text do render(
    # views/hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice.text.erb
    "hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice" )
  end
  format.pdf do render(
    # views/hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice.pdf.erb
    "hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice" )
  end
  format.html do render(
    # views/hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice.html.erb
    "hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice" )
  end
end
    . . .
```

Running the tests gives this result:

```
"~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views"
```

The above from puts( File.expand_path( 'views', File.dirname( **FILE** ) ).inspect )

The error message:

> Missing template hll_th_forex_mailer/forex_hll_commercial_rates with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :variants=>[],
>   :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
>   Searched in:
>           * "~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer"
>           * "~/hll_th_main/app/views"

There are two things here that I do not understand:

1. The argument passed to the renderer is:

   "hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice"

but the template looked for is:

```
hll_th_forex_mailer/forex_hll_commercial_rates
```

The template name is that of the calling method, which is the default.  But I have explicitly overridden this.

2. The template_path given in the call to the mail method appears to be ignored or at least munged in some unfathomable fashion to exclude the 'views' subdirectory.

   Searched in:
       * "~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer"

rather than what I expected:

```
"~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views"
```

Can somebody point out what I am supposed to pass to the mail method to make it find a template called:

```
~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views/hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice.text.erb
```

None of this was a problem when implementing the original script so it is definitely a RoR introduced complexity.

Additional info:

If I do this:

```
    mail( :to => recipients,
          :from => fm_address,
          :subject => subject,
          :template_name => "hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice",
          :template_path => File.dirname( __FILE__ ) + "/views"
        )
```

Then I see this:

> Missing template ~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views/hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice with "mailer". Searched in. . .

Which is where I want it to look at least.  However it is not finding this file:

ll ~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views/hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice*

-rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb byrnejb 2010 Oct 20 16:10 ~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views/hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice.text.erb

And when I add the recommended `do block` to find the text template:

```
    mail( :to => recipients,
          :from => fm_address,
          :subject => subject,
          :template_name => "hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice",
#          :template_path => File.expand_path( '/', 'views',
          :template_path => File.dirname( __FILE__ ) + "/views"
        ) do | format |
      format.text
      end
```

Then I see this:

> Missing template hll_th_forex_mailer/forex_hll_commercial_rates with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb,
>   :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
>       * "/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_main/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer"
>       * "/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_main/app/views"

Which ignores the template_path and template_name keys provided in the call to the mail method.

What is going on with this thing?

Even more info.

If I fully specify the template_name:

```
:template_name => "hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice.text.erb",
```

and eliminate the `do |format| block` then I get this result:

> Missing template
>   ~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views/hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice.text.erb
>   with "mailer". Searched in:
>           * "/home/byrnejb/Projects/Software/theHeart/code/hll_th_main/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views"

and yet this is what ls -l shows:

ls -l ~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views/hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice.text.erb

-rw-rw-r--. 1 byrnejb byrnejb 2010 Oct 20 16:10 ~/lib/hll_action_mailer/hll_th_forex_mailer/views/hll_th_forex_commercial_rates_notice.text.erb

Comment: Believe it or not. evidently having the render action in a do block completely ignore the values passed in the call to the mail method is a design 'feature' which the maintainers are not willing to contemplate changing. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18412

Comment: However, I have subsequently demonstrated that explicitly overriding the default template path using the class default method also has no effect. I have also experimentally determined that passing an explicit template_path and template_name in the method call, without a do end block after the method, also fails to find templates.